# How to continue script if "if" is false? Multiple "else"

Tags: bash, if-statement, arguments, sh, conditional-statements

So I have this script, I want the script to test for the second condition if "if" is false, which is in elif to test if its true. Unless its false, of which it continues and tests the next elif. Basically Multiple "else".

```
#Basically It turns a argument into a variable. Because that can't 
#work in an if function.
#What the script is doing is its setting variables for the python script
#What vvTHISvv does is it turns the argument into a variable. 
if [[ "$1" != "" ]]; then
    VAR="$1"
else
    VAR=.
fi
if [[ "$2" != "" ]]; then
    VAR2="$2"
else
    VAR2=.
fi
if [[ "$3" != "" ]]; then
    VAR3="$3"
else
    VAR3=.
fi


if [[ ${2} = ${VAR2} ]]
#${2} =  ${2}
then
    echo "I am condition number 1"
    #outputs a number
    ./script.py "${VAR}" "`cat ${VAR2}` `echo ${VAR3}`"
elif [[ ${3} = "${VAR3}" ]]
#${3} = ${3}
then
    echo "I am condition number 2"
    #outputs a number

    ./script.py "${VAR}" "`echo ${VAR2}` `cat ${VAR3}`"
elif [[ ${2} = "${VAR2}" ]] || [[ ${3} = "${VAR3}" ]]
then
    echo "I am condition number 3"
    #outputs a number
    ./script.py "${VAR}" "`cat ${VAR2}` `cat ${VAR3}`"
else 
    echo "I am condition number 4"
    #outputs a number
    ./script.py "${VAR}" "${VAR2} ${VAR3}"
fi
```

If I run according to the first condition, it works

```
I am condition number 1
#*Insert whatever that python script did. Lets say it outputs "2"
```

However if I test according to a condition number 2

```
I am condition number 1
#*insert a bunch of errors
#related to the fact that its rolling based on the first "if"
```

It doesn't work and just rolls for condition number 1.

If there was just two conditions I would just put a "if" and "else", but how do you do it with four conditions.

Anyway VAR and ${1} are the same thing, the reason why ones a variable is to go around the fact that the condition and argument in ./script.py are the same thing. And you can't exactly set those two equal to each other as a condition in an IF statement.

Comment: Your third condition will never be hit, as it is the first or the second condition, so one of these must already have been true. Other than that, I don't fully understand the question. What is wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: Bascially I want the script to go off of elif if if is false. So if the if it results in an error. Then it just skips it and moves on to the next one, elif.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] -- code *someone else can run* to see the problem themsleves? Replacing your `./script.py` with some `echo`s would help. Setting your variables to a specific value that causes your intended and actual output to differ (such that someone can run it themselves to see the problem and/or test a proposed fix), likewise. As it is, it's hard to know what you want.

Comment: BTW, as some stylistic asides unrelated to the question, backticks are strongly deprecated in favor of `$()`, and all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself -- your own names should be lowercase to prevent potential for conflicts. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html on the latter, and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete on the former.

Comment: To clarify: the reason Charles Duffy is asking for an MCVE is that the "I am condition number 1" branch will be executed *only* if `${1}` matches `${VAR2}` (with the latter treated as a glob pattern), so it it's important to know what their actual values are. Also, I'd recommend running your script through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll have a bunch of recommendations.

Comment: I'm sorry I should of made this more clear. So the Variables are basically arguments, what I'm doing is I'm inserting different arguments into a python script that has a different argument syntax then the bash script. The reason theres "cat" is because I'm trying to make it so it could also read files. The python script is using "sys.arg" to do arguments, that syntax is in the code. script.py outputs a number.

Comment: The specifics matter. If you run `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` to log each line as it's run, and then identify the first line where any test behaves other than how you expect, that would go a long way towards being able to simplify the question (taking everything unrelated to that single line out).

Answer (score -1):

Use `case`, (`./script.py` code omitted to show how the logic works):

```
# Assumes none of the variables contain a '#' -- change to some other
# nonexistent string if needed.
case "$2#$3" in 
    "${VAR2}#${VAR3}") echo both ;;
    "${VAR2}#"*)       echo 1st ;;
    *"#${VAR3}")       echo 2nd ;;
    *)                echo none ;;
esac
```

Since only two variables are compared to two corresponding strings, there's only four possible results.

`case` accepts multiple lines of code, just like `if`.  Using the first condition in the question, the code would become:

```
case "$2#$3" in 
    "${VAR2}#${VAR3}") echo both ;;
    "${VAR2}#"*)       echo "I am condition number 1"
                     ./script.py "${VAR}" "$(<${VAR2}) ${VAR3}" ;;
    *"#${VAR3}")       echo 2nd ;;
    *)                echo none ;;
esac
```

Comment: You haven't explained why the OP's code doesn't work. And why is this better than an an if/elif/else chain? Now there's the possibility for error when one of the values is a substring of the other. The cleverness has a cost.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, Re *"when one of the values is a substring of the other"*: Thanks.  Fixed now.

Comment: case doesn't seem to make a difference, even with the "*" to change it up, when the conditions is basically setting the variable to itself.

Comment: @CaucasianMalaysian, The question remains too vague as to input and output to give a more specific answer.  But the logic portion of the question is answerable.  Here `case` is correct and won't do anything unexpected, the conditional code is left up to you.  (Replace `echo both` *etc.* with any code that's appropriate).